# Add some content to woocommerce product single page via a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, constructor, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm somewhat new to developing plugins for Wordpress and I have this idea for a simple woocommerce based plugin. I need this plugin to do something only on single product pages but I can't see to figure out at all how I would add an action when a product gets loaded to do something.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

In my plugin I've attempted to just get this working with some code

```
public function get_product_variation_data() {
    function get_data() {
        echo '<script>';
        echo "console.log('beep');";
        echo '</script>';
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'get_data' );
}
```

But this doesn't seem to run at all on my product page. Maybe there is a different hook I need to attach to?

Comment: Sorry but I have answered before Alex … So that is not really fair as my answer is explaining the same thing than his answer. I hope that you will take that in consideration.

Comment: I didn't saw that you have answered when I posted mine, but if it is important for you, i can remove it and tell Jordan to accept yours ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
class PluginTest {
    public function __construct(){
       add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', array($this, 'get_product_variation_data'));
    }

    public function get_product_variation_data(){
       echo '<script>';
       echo "console.log('beep');";
       echo '</script>';
    }
}


$plugin_test = new PluginTest();
```

Comment: Good you just added missing quotes to 'get_product_variation_data'…

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in your plugin constructor `__construct()` the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', array( $this, 'get_product_variation_data' ), 5 );
```

Then outside the constructor:

```
public function get_product_variation_data() {
    ?> 
       <script> console.log('beep'); </script>
    <?php
}
```

This should work…

Comment: Beware of your single quotes. You need to escape those around "beep" or put double quotes. And replace `this` by `$this`.